# Where I spend time before the call to the action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **ANSWER** Please check your html structure.

I have controller and action.

```
public class HomeController
{
   private Stopwatch controller_action;
   public HomeController()
   {
        controller_action = new Stopwatch();
        controller_action.Start();
   }
   public ActionResult Cars(KendoDataSourceRequest request)
   {
      controller_action.Stop();
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(controller_action.Elapsed);
   }
}
```

I call action Cars from popup window.

My actions: 
I open popup and catch 100ms
I close popup
and I open popup and catch 200ms...

And this repeat again and again 100ms, 200, 300...

How check what happen after end constructor and before start action ?

**Update**
I used miniProfiler I have result:

[image]

this is only IE8 and IE9 in chrome all very well

Comment: I think what you want is a profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/). It is extremely easy to integrate to MVC, and will provide great info regarding your actions and what MVC is doing behind the scenes, directly in your application's UI.

You can also use it to add custom profiling messages, that can be automatically turned on during debugging but off for production code.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the MVC framework for .NET open source? You could download the source and find out.

<strike>The reason it keeps incrementing, though, is probably because a single instance of the controller is created, and re-used for multiple requests.</strike> No, nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Stopwatch.Stop() does not reset the Elapsed interval.
So it seems like if you close the popup & reopen it you get current time difference from the first Start() call.

Maybe your method should look like:

```
public ActionResult Cars(KendoDataSourceRequest request)
   {
      controller_action.Stop();
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(controller_action.Elapsed);
      controller_action.Restart();
   }
```

Comment: Conroller created all time if I call action from client side.